# Javascript compatibility issues (code works in FF but not in Opera and Chrome)

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

I have a code in Javascript as follows...

```
var btnOK = document.getElementById('btnOK');
btnOK.style.visibility = "visible";
var iframeControlObj = document.getElementById('iframe');
this.style.visibility = "hidden";
var file_xml = iframeControlObj.contentDocument.getElementById('hiddenxml');
file_xml.value = xml_value;
iframeControlObj.contentWindow.location.reload();
```

## Explanation

I have an iframe in which there is a control "hiddenxml". I want to send the data into the iframe from the current webpage. So, I am initializing the value to the "hiddenxml" and reloading the iframe.

## Problem

In Firefox, I am able to get "xml_value" through the "hiddenxml", but in Chrome and Opera, I am unable to get this information it.

Please let me know why this is happening. If this is a trash method, please feel free to give a better method and improve it. Thanks a lot..

PS: The xml_value can be quite large, about 3-4 MB in size. xml_value is a string and not a DOM object

Comment: When you reload the iframe, it refreshes everything from the server, and any modifications you've made to the DOM are lost.

Comment: What is a solution for it ?? How can I send the information from the current page into the iframe ??

Comment: Do it in the other order: reload the frame and then send the data.

Comment: Actually, there is a Javascript code present in the IFrame, which automatically executes when the reload occurs. This function which I have written performs the operation over "hiddenxml". Hence, reload -> assign data chronology wont work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exchange data between your page and an iframe you can use

```
window.postMessage
```

The Mozilla Documentation about this is quite good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: window.postMessage sends value through the URL. The xml_value is quite large as I have already mentioned, so I cant send that huge value through the URL. Thanks for your response though.