# Persistent DOM Object on Page Reload

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

This question may seem a little out of the block, but it actually gave me a pretty hard time.

DOM objects in Google Chrome and Opera are actually **reload-transient**. That is, if you create a textbox in a html page and refresh the page, the information in the textbox vanishes. While, the same DOM objects in IE and Firefox are **reload-persistent**. That is, the textbox retains its value after refresh, unless a javascript code is written to prevent the same.

All the 4 browsers have scored 100 in Acid 3 tests, but still they are different in this aspect. Can anyone actually help me out why this difference is actually present ? Is it because of the underlying layout engines (like gecko for Firefox, presto for Opera etc.) or is it the ideology of the browser designers ?

This problem actually gave me a pretty hard time to make my website compatible for the browsers, since my code expected a hidden field in my iframe to retain its value after the reload. A detailed information of my problem has been written in this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21950656/javascript-compatibility-issues-code-works-in-ff-but-not-in-opera-and-chrome).

It is an interesting phenomenon which I came across and would be more than happy if someone can share their thoughts on this.

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 0):

If the text boxes are in an html form, you can use the form's `reset()` method to return the text boxes to their default state. If you're using jQuery you could do something like:

```
$('form').each(function(index, formElement){
    formElement.reset();
});
```

Comment: Hi, actually, my question revolves more into why there is such inconsistency rather than how to reset the DOM objects.